# Solr cloud/index keep on looping on recovery mode

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr4

Solr cloud/index keep on looping on recovery mode

We are using solr 4.10.4. Any nodes goes on recovery on solr cloud it tries to keep on looping for index creation.
I can see these indexes are getting merged and then starting again to create, this goes on and on . During recovery if we stop writing/updating it is able to recover. We can't stop everytime any goes on recovery.

```
73G     /solr/rn0/data/index.20190702175353942
72G     /solr/rn0/data/index.20190702180925887
4.0K    /solr/rn0/data/index.properties
4.0K    /solr/rn0/data/replication.properties
1.2G    /solr/rn0/data/tlog
```

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FpNx.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igZfW.png)

Comment: There have been massive improvements to the cloud functionality in the many years since Solr 4. This isn't the answer you're looking for, but it's really time to start considering upgrading to a more recent version when using SolrCloud - possibly to avoid issues like this.

Comment: I agree, Solr is now available in version 8, you are missing 4 majors by now ...

Comment: Yes @MatsLindh agree, but we have legacy production system, we need to solve it. Yes to use latest/upgraded environment we need some time to do that. It is not quickly doable at this moment.